# Have a completed project written with global vars, should I replace with pass by reference?

Tags: c, pass-by-reference, global

I've finished a project that relies heavily on string manipulation in C. The problem is that should I change my global variables to pass by reference instead? Code is longer than 300 lines, and the global variables seem to be doing fine. I've read other posts that pbr can increase readability.

I have about 6 global vars.

Comment: There's no such thing as pass-by-reference in C.

Comment: @AntoineMathys: Nope, you're passing the pointer address by value. Pointers are not references (and vice-versa).

Comment: Pointers do represent a reference, namely one to a location in memory. They are just not the same as the C++ language concept called references, but since this is not about C++ that is not relevant.

Comment: Global variables can seriously inhibit reuse of code. If you don't think the code will be reused, then the globals may not matter very much. If the code might be the basis for a library, global variables are problematic. If the code might be used in a multi-threaded applications, global variables require synchronization. Global constants are less of a problem, though any global is a source of 'namespace pollution' and can cause naming conflicts. In multi-file programs, use as many static (rather than global) functions and variables as possible. For thread safety, avoid even static variables.

Comment: hold on, i'm confused, so is pass by pointers in C in essence doing the same function as pass by reference in C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always aim to keep your state as small as reasonably possible. Having big state (roughly: at any point in the code, the number of accessible (dependable) variables is high) means more more responsibility at each point, more difficult maintenance, less intuitive to read.

So yes, global variables only where you can't bear passing them to every little function.

If you have a throw-away program, global state is obviously ok, but then you normally don't start in C in the first place.

6 global vars doesn't sound much, but you can't generalize.